# receiving error when using if statements with a constant variable - C

Tags: c, constants

I have `#define MAX_PERSONS = 20;` after my headers.
I'm trying to do an if statement, where I compare an int p to MAX_PERSONS

```
int checkString(char string[]){
   int p = strlen(string);
   printf("\n\t\t%s is %d characters long\n", string, p);
   if (p < MAX_PERSONS){
       return 1;
   }
   if (p > 20){
       return 0;
   }
}
```

I receive this error `menu.c:80:10: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token`.
However, if I switch MAX_PERSONS to 20 like how I did with the second if statement, it works.

I was wondering if someone could let me know why this is happening and how I can use the constant value. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
#define MAX_PERSONS = 20;
```

with

```
#define MAX_PERSONS 20
```

`#define` is a pr-processor directive which replaces `MAX_PERSONS` with the followed text before compilation.

Comment: Doh, thank you. Thought I defined it correctly the entire time.

Comment: @user1730056 you can accept if it solves your problem.Try avoiding Thank you comments on SO.

Comment: Was just waiting for the 15 mins to pass to accept!